# Не могу разобраться со splice(

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js

Изначальная позиция карточек
[image: Изначальная позиция карточек]

Перетаскиваю и отпускаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат корректный: 002, 003, 004, 005, 001
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если попробую перетащить так
[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]
Произошло удаление и сбой в номерах, а должно было быть 002, 001, 003, 004, 005
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код который у меня написан (помогите пож. как правильно переписать, чтоб работал как нужно):

```
movingBoards(currentIndex, newIndex) {
      const currentItem = this.todoList[currentIndex];

      this.todoList.splice(currentIndex, 1);
      this.todoList[newIndex] = currentItem;
}
```

В `this.todoList` у меня вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй подставить свои значения и посмотри что получается

Comment: Так я подставил, но не могу понять как сделать перемещение элементов( Чтоб не было этого бага с удалением

Comment: продолжать использовать splice, вместо `=`

Comment: Большое спасибо,       this.todoList.splice(currentIndex, 1);
      this.todoList.splice(newIndex, 0, currentItem); так помогло. Только не пойму в чем разница, почему через = не работало так как нужно(

Comment: потому что объект ссылочного типа и получается что 2 строка кода удаляет то что сохранено в первой строке и третья строка уже не в силе это добавить - объекта нет, в случае со сплайсом нет никаких конфликтов ссылок  this.todoList.splice(newIndex, 0, currentItem); только мне кажется тут вместо 0 должна быть 1 т.е. в одну команду без  this.todoList.splice(currentIndex, 1);

Comment: @DaniilLoban, в одну строку не получится, потому что newIndex и currentIndex могут не совпадать

Comment: @DaniilLoban Можно и ответ оформить.

Comment: @Grundy абсолютно верно, я не учел что элементов может быть 2

Answer (score 1):

Так как позиции могут быть разные то нужно вызывать splice дважды (для каждого элемента)

```
// перемещаем второй элемент на позицию первого
const [first] = todoList.splice(currentIndex, 1, todoList[newIndex]);
// перемещаем первый элемент на позицию второго
todoList.splice(newIndex, 1, first);
```

В целях демонстрации я решил основываться не на данных а на элементах DOM дерева (так меньше кода и наглядно). Для перемещения нужно сделать 2 клика - откуда и куда:

```js
const line =  document.querySelector('.line')
const todoList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.board'))

let currentIndex = -1;
let newIndex = -1;

const movingBoards = () => {
   if (currentIndex !== newIndex){ // если позиции разные
     // перемещаем второй элемент на позицию первого
     const [first] = todoList.splice(currentIndex, 1, todoList[newIndex]);
     // перемещаем первый элемент на позицию второго
     todoList.splice(newIndex, 1, first);
     // обновляем DOM дерево
     todoList.forEach(e => line.appendChild(e)) 
     // cбрасываем индексы
   }
   currentIndex = newIndex = -1;
}

line.addEventListener('click', (event)=> {
  if (event.target.className === 'board'){
    const index = todoList.findIndex((e) => e  === event.target)
    if (currentIndex === -1){
      currentIndex = index
    } else {
      newIndex = index
      movingBoards(currentIndex, newIndex)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
}
.board {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #394165;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="board">001</div>
  <div class="board">002</div>
  <div class="board">003</div>
  <div class="board">004</div>
  <div class="board">005</div>
</div>
```